# Is there a better way to link up XML elements with java classes in Android than findViewById()

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, layout

While I would like to make everything programatically whenever I can, and leave XML blank, that is not possible where I work (designers will not work with raw program code...)

So, to that extend, almost every one of my activity that I work with or built contains a large block of findViewById at the start somewhere.

This is especially painful if I had to create it from scratch and I am now allowed to programatically create an array of buttons and add it to the layout... Thankfully they will let me do that if it gets to 10+ elements and they are all the same type.

Is there a way to avoid this? Or a way to make it automatically cast it into what I am assigning it to? So I don't need to type Button mButton = (Button) findview...

If there is some way to automagically generate java instances of buttons and what nots from the XML given the layout that would be great (esp if the names were nice and autocompleteable).

Comment: You can also use TAG's, then when you create your Button just add in your for loop : button.setTag(Button.class.getSimpleName()+i) , then when you need you can find your button with view.findViewWithTag(Button.class.getSimpleName()+i);

Comment: I mean from XML as a way, adding tags is good to refer them from other places where the array of Button or what nots is not easily accessible, but not what I am trying to do.

Comment: http://androidannotations.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Android annotations](http://androidannotations.org/)
AndroidAnnotations is an Open Source framework that speeds up Android development. It takes care of the plumbing, and lets you concentrate on what's really important. By simplifying your code, it facilitates its maintenance.
Here is a simple example of how your code can dramatically shrink, and become much easier to understand:
**Before** `Android Annotations`

```
public class BookmarksToClipboardActivity extends Activity {

  BookmarkAdapter adapter;

  ListView bookmarkList;

  EditText search;

  BookmarkApplication application;

  Animation fadeIn;

  ClipboardManager clipboardManager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(FLAG_FULLSCREEN, FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.bookmarks);

    bookmarkList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bookmarkList);
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    application = (BookmarkApplication) getApplication();
    fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, anim.fade_in);
    clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    View updateBookmarksButton1 = findViewById(R.id.updateBookmarksButton1);
    updateBookmarksButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        updateBookmarksClicked();
      }
    });

    View updateBookmarksButton2 = findViewById(R.id.updateBookmarksButton2);
    updateBookmarksButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        updateBookmarksClicked();
      }
    });

    bookmarkList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView p, View v, int pos, long id) {
        Bookmark selectedBookmark = (Bookmark) p.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
        bookmarkListItemClicked(selectedBookmark);
      }
    });

    initBookmarkList();
  }

  void initBookmarkList() {
    adapter = new BookmarkAdapter(this);
    bookmarkList.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  void updateBookmarksClicked() {
    UpdateBookmarksTask task = new UpdateBookmarksTask();

    task.execute(search.getText().toString(), application.getUserId());
  }

  private static final String BOOKMARK_URL = //
  "http://www.bookmarks.com/bookmarks/{userId}?search={search}";


  class UpdateBookmarksTask extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected Bookmarks doInBackground(String... params) {
      String searchString = params[0];
      String userId = params[1];

      RestTemplate client = new RestTemplate();
      HashMap args = new HashMap();
      args.put("search", searchString);
      args.put("userId", userId);
      HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
      HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
      ResponseEntity response = client.exchange( //
          BOOKMARK_URL, HttpMethod.GET, request, Bookmarks.class, args);
      Bookmarks bookmarks = response.getBody();

      return bookmarks;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bookmarks result) {
      adapter.updateBookmarks(result);
      bookmarkList.startAnimation(fadeIn);
    }

  }

  void bookmarkListItemClicked(Bookmark selectedBookmark) {
    clipboardManager.setText(selectedBookmark.getUrl());
  }

}
```

**After:**

```
@NoTitle
@Fullscreen
@EActivity(R.layout.bookmarks)
public class BookmarksToClipboardActivity extends Activity {

  BookmarkAdapter adapter;

  @ViewById
  ListView bookmarkList;

  @ViewById
  EditText search;

  @App
  BookmarkApplication application;

  @RestService
  BookmarkClient restClient;

  @AnimationRes
  Animation fadeIn;

  @SystemService
  ClipboardManager clipboardManager;

  @AfterViews
  void initBookmarkList() {
    adapter = new BookmarkAdapter(this);
    bookmarkList.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Click({R.id.updateBookmarksButton1, R.id.updateBookmarksButton2})
  void updateBookmarksClicked() {
    searchAsync(search.getText().toString(), application.getUserId());
  }

  @Background
  void searchAsync(String searchString, String userId) {
    Bookmarks bookmarks = restClient.getBookmarks(searchString, userId);
    updateBookmarks(bookmarks);
  }

  @UiThread
  void updateBookmarks(Bookmarks bookmarks) {
    adapter.updateBookmarks(bookmarks);
    bookmarkList.startAnimation(fadeIn);
  }

  @ItemClick
  void bookmarkListItemClicked(Bookmark selectedBookmark) {
    clipboardManager.setText(selectedBookmark.getUrl());
  }

}
```

Comment: That looks really useful, does it does the generation automatically in eclipse and can we change the generated android code without change the annotations?

I ask since if this gets passed on, and the guys don't know what this is they will think I coded in some weird language and not Android if they opened the project and all they see is something like this in the source.

Comment: They will see your source code. Just add comment what you use android annotations. All generated files will stored in a separate folder(`apt_generated`) in your project. Generated code is a standard java code with findViewById(), setOnClickListener(), etc.

Comment: sweet thanks! this helps a lot and will be trying it and at worse replacing the annotations with the generated code if things go wrong with the other devs / designers.